# Working with tuples in Halide

Tags: c++11, halide

I want to extract one channel in Halide,

```
Halide::Image<uint8_t> input = load_image("images/rgb.png");
Halide::Var x, y;
Halide::Func green;
green(x,y)= {0, input(x, y, 1), 0};

Halide::Image<uint8_t> output =
        green.realize(input.width(), input.height());
```

gives

> Can only cast single-element realizations to buffers or images

it must be simple

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a three channel output in which two are all zero  and one is the content of the corresponding channel of the input image. To do this, try:

```
   green(x, y, c) = select(c == 1, input(x, y, 1), 0);
```

If this is unrolled and bounded, there will be no conditional evaluation in the execution.

Comment: in the tutorial it is discouraged to use "select" in such cases.

Comment: also it produces ugly code 
   for c=0 to 3 { for y=0 to height { for x=0 to width {  }}}

Comment: Presumably you mean this comment from tutorial 13:
    // 2) It requires a select, which can impact performance if not
    // bounded and unrolled:
    // brighter.bound(c, 0, 3).unroll(c);
which pretty much states exactly what I wrote. You have to bound the c dimension and unroll the loop on that dimension.

You could alternatively use an expression like "input(x, y, c) * (c == 1)" but I'd be surprised if that produces better code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
green(x, y) = input(x, y, 1);
```

The thing you have creates a tuple of three output images, two of which are zero.

Comment: no I want color image, with only green channel values >0

Comment: your code extracts one channel and gives grey image (fills all 3 channels with same value)